# how to convert date to another date with format?

Tags: php

I'm having problem with converting a date into another formatted date. Need help.

Trying to convert " 28-03-14 "  to " 2014-03-28 "

here's my code:

```
$sr=strtotime('28-03-14');
$dateto = date('Y-M-d',$sr);

echo $dateto;
```

Comment: What's the problem with your current code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
$input = '28-03-14';
$expld = explode("-",$input);
$input =$expld[2]."-".$expld[1]."-".$expld[0];
$date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($input));
echo $date;
?>
```

Comment: :)
but i below consider answer as more reliable solution. i dnt know abt that below one.

Answer (score 2):

Do the OOP way ;)

```
<?php
//28-03-14 " to " 2014-03-28 "
$MyDate="28-03-14";
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('d-m-y',$MyDate); 
echo $newformat=$date->format('Y-m-d'); // "prints" 2014-03-28
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$curDate = strtotime('28-03-14');
$newDate = date('Y-m-d', $curDate);
```

If you think date as a string:

```
$newDate = implode('-', array_reverse(explode('-', $curDate)));
```